# Layouts appears differently on real device

Tags: android, layout, graphical-layout-editor

The layout I'm designing appears fine in graphical layout but when I install it on the device it screws up.

Graphical Layout

[image]

On device

[image]

Here is my layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/home_background" 
     >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="81dp" 
        android:scrollbars="none"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/flipkart" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/dominos" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/flipkart" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dotted_separator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dotted_separator" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="30dp" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/title_holder"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/find_restaurant_coupons"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="Find Restaurant Coupons"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/spinner_holder"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/title_holder"
            >
             <!--
             <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/city_spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/city_spinner_data"
                />   
  -->
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/location_search_holder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_holder"
            >
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Location"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_go"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/input_location"
                android:background="#17b851"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="GO" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/best_restaurants_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="42dp"
        android:background="#17b851"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:text="Best Restaurants Offers" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what the problem was. I again stared with a blank file and copied each block one at a time to narrow down the problem but to my surprise this time it shows up properly.